# Oracle loud BI Reporting : Xls template

Tags: xls, bi-publisher, oracle-fusion-apps

I am developing a report in BI report using xsl template. I have a doubt regarding adding two fields. In rtf template we use `<?xdofx: field1 + field2?>`. But if I do the same in xls template, it shows an error
'Namespace prefix 'xdofx' used but not declared'. Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

I made a table in an RTF file using `<?xdofx: value1 + value2?>`. And rendered with Excel output as preview.

Try removing the `xdofx:` part. It's not necessary in the RTF template.